# How to get Lookahead/Lookbehind position?

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to get the Lookahead/Lookbehind position.
Example:

```
String text = "one two three";
String pattern = "(?<=two )three";
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
while(m.find()){
 System.out.println(m.start() + " - " + m.end())
}
```

Output is "8 - 13" but I need to get the position where lookbehind ("two") starts: "4 - 13".
Is it possible?

Comment: Then capture the lookbehind pattern (`(?<=(two ))three`) and use `m.start(1)` instead of `m.start()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! That's really a nice solution! Thanks! Would it be possible to get the same result without any changes in regex?

Comment: No, you cannot. Lookbehind patterns are non-consuming patterns.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to do this which avoids regex and instead uses the base string functions:

```java
String text = "one two three";
String sub = "two three";
int start = text.indexOf(sub);
int end = start + sub.length();
System.out.println(start + " - " + end);  // 4 - 13
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but I have a regex in my code and it would be generally very difficult to replace it. So I need the solution only with regex..

Comment: Doing it your current way seems very roundabout.  Why must you use regular expressions for this?

Comment: I already have a class where regex is used everywhere and other classes use methods of this class. So it would be too cumbersome to override it, mainly because everything works as intended, only I need to get the position of lookbehind in addition to the start and end indices of my match. I.e. I need 8 - 13 as a result and additionally 4 - 18 (whole match with lookbehind)